# Javascript Code for MVC Dropdownlist OnChange Event

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html-select

I am having problems catching the change event of a Dropdownlist in an MVC project. My goal is to use the first dropdown to populate the second. The first step is to catch the change event which I cannot seem to do despite two days of never ending trials. Here are a couple of the methods I’ve tried to no avail.

**This is the form that contains the dropdown lists. The second dropdown is in a partial view.**

```
<form id="TheForm" method="get">
<p>
    @Html.DropDownList("scanners", (SelectList)ViewBag.scanners, "---Select A Scanner---")
</p>

<div id="results">
    @{Html.RenderAction("ProtocolDDL", "CTProtocols");}
</div>
```

**Here’s my javascript code trial 1.**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#scanners").change(function () {
        $("#TheForm").submit();
    });
});
</script>
```

**Here’s trial 2.**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#scanners").change(function () {
            var selection = $("#scanners").val(); //get the selection made in the dropdownlist
            $('#results').load("/CTProtocols/ProtocolReview/" + selection); //return value of the url /locations/sites which is the action method to invoke.
        })
    });
</script>
```

I’ve tried many other iterations but none have worked.

Comment: definitely go with trial 2.  couple of things you can try. first thing to check.  if you look at the rendered drop down.  does id="scanners"?

Comment: Thanks, Matt. Yes, the id and name are set to scanners. Copied from source: <select id="scanners" name="scanners">

Comment: perfect.  if this is a timing issue (item hasn't loaded when the page is loaded) you will need to tie the event to the document.  try changing your selector to $(document).on('change', '#scanners', function() {

Comment: Thanks. I’ll try that. Is there any way to debug and determine if the javascript code is being called and just not working?

Comment: every browser has a tool for that.  I prefer firebug with firefox.  Once you install the add on.  click f12 to open the developer console.  you can put breakpoints in the script from there and see if it is getting hit

Comment: Thanks, Matt. I’ll look at that and report back. The change in selector did not produce anything different.

Comment: Have you tried using jquery to attach an event to the element - jquery .ON REF [link](http://api.jquery.com/on/) ....just saw Matt's response, ignore mine...lol

Comment: I believe the issue is the loading of the jquery library. Firebug is telling that $ is not defined. I do have a src script loading jquery and have tried it in several locations.

Comment: OK. So I got the jquery fixed. To get the form to submit I resorted to the first approach. Am going to try and get # 2 to work now. It isn’t liking the on(change...) approach.

Comment: use the change method to make an ajax call with the selected valyue from the first dropdown and then return a json with the values for the second dropdown, use these values in a `.each()` in jquery to construct your second dropdown